# jQuery get length td match data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, each, custom-data-attribute

I would like to get row count by data attribute, for example, `data-engine` with `ami` match `3`, what method could possible to get count or length?

Note: the data-engine value as `ami` come from a smarty template variable. So, i need target data-engine instated of `ami`

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable();
    
     let data_engines = [];
    $('#table_id').find('td[data-engine]').each(function () {
        let data_engine = $(this).attr('data-engine');
        if ($.inArray(data_engine, data_engines) == -1) {
            data_engines.push(data_engine);
        }
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < data_engines.length; i++) {
        let count = $('#table_id').find('td[data-engine="' + data_engines[i] + '"]').length;
        let option_engine = `<option value="${data_engines[i]}">${data_engines[i]} : ${count}</option>`;
        $('.snds').append(option_engine);
    }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.11.3/b-2.0.1/fc-4.0.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.11.3/b-2.0.1/fc-4.0.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.css"/>

<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ami">Apple</td>
            <td>Mango</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ami">Mengo</td>
            <td>Apple 2</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td data-engine="ciam">Apple</td>
            <td>Mango</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ami">Banana</td>
            <td>Oliv</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ciam">Oliv</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
============================================<br>
Dropdown:
<select class="snds" id="aeid">
<option value="ami">ami</option>
<option value="ciam">ciam</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2:

```js
    let data_engines = [];
    $('#table_id').find('td[data-engine]').each(function () {
        let data_engine = $(this).attr('data-engine');
        if ($.inArray(data_engine, data_engines) == -1) {
            data_engines.push(data_engine);
        }
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < data_engines.length; i++) {
        let count = $('#table_id').find('td[data-engine="' + data_engines[i] + '"]').length;
        let text = `${data_engines[i]} : ${count}`;
        $('.snds').find(`option[value="${data_engines[i]}"]`).text(text);
    }
```

```html
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ami">Apple</td>
            <td>Mango</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ami">Mengo</td>
            <td>Apple 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ciam">Apple</td>
            <td>Mango</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ami">Banana</td>
            <td>Oliv</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ciam">Oliv</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<select class="snds" id="aeid">
    <option value="ami">ami</option>
    <option value="ciam">ciam</option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: check my update !!

Comment: you can  do this by append every option element inside for, check update

Comment: I have edited again my question. Added datatable including your script.  My dropdown already have options, just wanna append the count with option text. e.g. `existing option : 3`  just append the `: 3` kindly check the issue.

Comment: check my update, that's what do you want ??

Comment: Exactly i wanted and the solution is near about 90%. Its working here but i don't know not working for me. When i am using your script, the whole datatable stop working without no error in console. When i am removing last 2 lines of your script, the datatable working back. I think last 2 lines has issue with syntax or symbol.

Comment: I got the issue, when i am using the script it in js file, its working, but when i am using it my template .tpl file, the last 2 lines are conflict, why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237533/discussion-between-smaller-and-younes-bennour).

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter object to track counts then iterate that object to update the display

```js
const engines = {};

$('td[data-engine]').each((i,el) => engines[el.dataset.engine] = (engines[el.dataset.engine]||0) +1)

$.each(engines, (k, v) => $('#engines').append( $('<div>', {text:`Found ${k} :${v}`})))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ami">Apple</td>
            <td>Mango</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ami">Mengo</td>
            <td>Apple 2</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td data-engine="ciam">Apple</td>
            <td>Mango</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ami">Banana</td>
            <td>Oliv</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-engine="ciam">Oliv</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
============================================<br>
<div id="engines"></div>
```